# Why does assets sometimes not loaded in heroku (rails4 app)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have installed 'rails_12 factor' gem to serve static assets in heroku. I have precompiled the assets in production and development environment before pushing the app. I have added the following line in "application.css" for this issue.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Special+Elite);
```

But sometimes assets not loading properly in heroku. Please suggest me some ideas.

I also configured in "application.rb" like

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Whether this line keep the assets persistently loaded in heroku?